# Получение переменной из базы данных в htaccess. настройка понятных человеку ссылок

Tags: .htaccess, чпу, opencart

Делаю мультимагазин с поддоменами. Поддомены на хостинге создала, в админке магазины создала, товары по магазинам раскидала.

Надо чтобы каждый товар открывался с поддоменом производителя в основном магазине.

Обе ссылки — и `поддомен.домен.ру/товар`, и `домен.ру/товар` — доступны.

Хочу сделать «склейку 301» через `.htaccess`.

Самый просто вариант - получить из таблички базы данных значение переменной *название производителя* (можно прямо эту переменную и вставить в *url*) или *айдишника* на крайний случай, и проверкой сделать редирект.

Как получить переменную из базы данных через `.htaccess`?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, htaccess не позволяет работать с БД. Для этих задач нужно использовать скрипт PHP, Perl или другое, чтобы читать запрос, сравнивать URI и выдавать в заголовок 301, 302 или другие заголовки. В htaccess в этом случае прописывается RewriteRule полностью переводящим запросы на скрипт.

Answer (score 2):

> самый просто вариант - получить из таблички базы данных значение переменной *название производителя* (можно прямо эту переменную и вставить в *url*) или айдишника на крайний случай, и проверкой сделать редирект.

да, это не только самый простой, но и самый разумный вариант (два других, с ходу приходящих в голову варианта — написание собственного *http*-сервера, или постоянное обновление файла `.htaccess` по мере изменения в базе данных, вряд ли можно назвать разумными для решения задачи «запуск интернет-магазина»).

средствами `.htaccess` в подобной ситуации обычно реализуется вызов какой-нибудь точки входа (например, индексного файла) при любом полученном *url*-е, не соответствующем какому-то существующему файлу/каталогу. в таком примерно духе:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

а уже внутри файла-обработчика (в приведённом примере — содержащего исполняемый скрипт на языке *php*) делаются обращения к базе, проверки *url*-а, и, при необходимости, возврат браузеру какого-нибудь из [перенаправляющих ответов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP#.D0.9F.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B0.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B2.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5) (чаще используют 301-й) с новым *url*-ом.